# How to solve Critical Logical Driver

Tags: raid, log, error-handling

I was checking the logs in server when i came across this message.

```
Nov 4 12:52:05 SERVERNAME ServeRAID Manager Agent:
[338] Periodic scan found one or more critical logical drives: controller 1. 
Repair as soon aspossible to avoid data loss.
```

1. What does this mean?
2. Is it Critical or can be ignored?
3. If critical how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formal discription for this is:

> A hard disk drive is defunct in the specified logical drive. The data on this logical drive is at risk. If another hard disk drive fails, the data might be lost.

1. It means 1 of the hard discs or 1 of the controllers is failing;
2. Critical;
3. Replace the disc or controller.

That is... it could also be that the scan is done while a rebuild operation is in progress. In that case you need to redo the scan after the rebuild is done.

It is a common error message when dealing with RAID (failure of hard discs is not that uncommon) that should be dealt with as soon as it shows up. The next error message might be fatal.

Comment: So what u r saying is that during boot time Hard Disk scan happens during the RAID array rebuild was in progress. Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: No. I said: IF there is a rebuild active and the scan happens during the rebuild this message will also appear. You should always scan when there is no rebuild active. If at that time this message appears then it is a serious one.

Comment: Oh man didnt get a word. Kindly provide more info on REBUILD of what and Scan of what. I have not much knowledge on this thing. But yes it does seem a logical drive has some fault. With ur further information Im sure I will be able to solve this issue. Thanks take care

Comment: Ok issue is solved by removing the the faulty HDD and rebuilding the Array

Comment: cool! very nice @UmairMustafa :) :)